# Is there a design pattern that I can use for applying a list of functions to create machine learning features in python?

Tags: python, design-patterns, refactoring

I am working on building an address parsing tool in python for labeling address parts. I have a pandas data frame that looks something like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"TOKEN": ['123.', 'Fake', 'street']})
```

And I've got a number of feature functions that look like this:

```
def f_ends_in_period(s):
    return 'f_ends_in_period' if s[-1] == "." else ''

def f_numeric(s):
    return 'f_numeric' if any([k.isdigit() for k in s]) else ''

def f_capitalized(s):
    return 'f_capitalized' if s[0].isupper() else ''
...
```

The feature functions are fairly rigid. A feature function `f_blah(s)` returns "f_blah" if string `s` satisfies some condition (namely, condition "blah"), and otherwise returns an empty string. It's a little weird but there's a method to the madness.

Anyway, for now what I'm doing is simply going down the list

```
df['f_ends_in_period'] = df['TOKEN'].apply(f_ends_in_period)
df['f_numeric'] = df['TOKEN'].apply(f_numeric)
df['f_capitalized'] = df['TOKEN'].apply(f_capitalized)
```

And that works fine, except that every time I want to make a new feature function, I have to type the name of that feature function at least 4 times. That starts to get annoying really fast, especially if I want to create dozens of features.

Is there sort of a standard pattern that I can use to refactor this? I'm not sure exactly what the solution looks like, I'm just looking for suggestions to streamline this process.

Comment: Interesting question. Why not have a 'super feature function' that receives df as parameter, and applies all feature functions?

Comment: @JavoSN this is close to what I was thinking.. I thought maybe turn feature functions into methods of some class that also has a method for executing all the feature functions on a dataframe. But I can't quite see how to make that work the way I want.

Comment: Why not keep your functions in a container and loop over the container, applying the functions in a loop?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, I see that as a partial solution.. but I still need to type the name of the function at least 3 times. Each time I add a feature function, I also have to add it to the container.

Comment: Yes, well, it's the fool-proof way of doing it. I don't think writing `my_funcs.append(func)` right after you define `func` is really that onerous.

Comment: Yes. The classical object oriented approach would be to extend DataFrame class, into ValidatedDataFrame for example, and add methods like 'is_numeric()' and 'ends_in_period()' for each feature function. Then have a super method that calls this.is_numeric(), this.ends_in_period(), etc. and returns a dictionary with all results, since you're adding the results to a dictionary anyways.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, I think you're right. But that also doesn't get at the other optimization that I see, which is that each of the feature functions returns its own name.

Comment: Honestly, I don't really follow what you are trying to do here. Instead of strings representing binary features, I would use booleans. If you care about optimizing things.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in this piece of code

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
import my_module

functions_list = [o for o in getmembers(my_module) if isfunction(o[1])]
```

It returns a list of tuples with all the functions from the module together with their names as string.

Answer (score 0):

A pythonic solution is to use a list of functions and then a comprehension to build a result list. Here's an example that could get you on the way:

```
def f_ends_in_period(s):
    return 'f_ends_in_period' if s[-1] == "." else ''

def f_numeric(s):
    return 'f_numeric' if any([k.isdigit() for k in s]) else ''

funcs = [f_ends_in_period, f_numeric]

result = [f(s) for f in funcs]
```

You'd only have to add the method or function once and then add it to the func list definition.

Edit: you could combine Elmex80s answer with mine and thus programatically build the function list, maybe even by filtering by function name. For instance, get all member functions whose name starts with "validate_", and then iterate through that list with te code above.